# Where do Chaos stand with Tyranids? Are they pro or against?

Tags: warhammer-40k

So Chaos can't corrupt Tyranids, but Chaos like death. So where do the Chaos Gods stand on in the Tyranids? Do they like them, fear them, hate them? Just seems odd to me.

Comment: I suppose it might vary from god to god. Like perhaps Nurgle and Khorne would be more ok with Tyranids than Slannesh or Tzeentch. My guess is really that everyone would be happy to kill Tyranids.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### The Chaos Gods would most probably hate the Tyranids.

It's hard to find anything canon pertaining to a Chaos god's opinion on Tryanids. It's reasonable to assume that Khorne would like 'nids, due to all the killing. Tzeentch too maybe, because a 'nid fleet would *change* an entire system's inhabitants into biomass.

But as a whole, I would assume that Chaos really dislikes the Tyranids:

They have absolutley no control over them and they cannot lure or bait them in any way. The 'nid hive mind is too powerful to be swayed and is above feelings of anger, fear or lust.

Worse yet, Chaos requires worshippers, lots and lots of worshippers. So if a Tyranid fleet decends on a Choas controled system, regardless of the outcome, there are going to be a lot fewer fanatics to worship Chaos in the aftermath.

Also, and maybe most importantly, the 'nids take absolutley no pleasure in the slaughter and mayhem they create. Their only goal is to consume more biomass and thus create more and more 'nids.

- They don't kill for fun or entertainment.
- They don't kill each other.
- They don't purposefully torture or enslave anyone. (Maybe Genestealers...)
- They don't defile monuments to The Emperor or Primarchs.
- They don't do anything Chaos gods want their followers to do.

Comment: I think you're right. No suffering, no souls and no enslavement make for no gain for chaos.

Comment: So are you guys thinking what I'm thinking? Battle brothers with Eldar?!? :D

Comment: I'd say rather with Necrons, 'nids and 'crons are two sides of the same omnicidal coin.

Comment: @Yasskier and unfortunately, 'nids would never bother attcking necrons because they ain't got no bio-matter to offer up. A large scale war between thos two would be awesome.

Answer (score 6):

Chaos gods are all about passion (which was the reason the atheistic [Imperial Truth](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Truth) didn't hurt them as much as Emperor wanted):

- Khorne is about passion for killing
- Tzeentch is about boundless ambition for power and knowledge
- Slaneesh is about pleasure and pain
- Nurgle is about the will to continue your existence no matter the conditions

Tyranids, similar to Necrons lack the passion: they simply want to feed, increase its biomass and keep feeding again. They don't take pleasure from killing, they are not interested in power, they don't pursue the pleasures and they can adapt to all the conditions they live in without the need to sacrifice their souls (not mentioning that they are arguably immune to diseases... and they don't have individual souls).

So in other words, **those four** Chaos gods would treat them as a threat. But the fifth chaos god - [Malal/Malice](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Malice) would probably welcome them, exactly because they provide threat and destruction to Chaos:

```
"We shall deny Nurgle their flesh to fester and rot."
"We shall deny Khorne their blood and skulls."
"We shall deny Tzeentch their destinies and fates."
"We shall deny Slaanesh their pleasure and pain."
"Death to the Dark Gods!"
"For the Renegade God!"
"Let the galaxy burn!"
```